# the same role in wordpress doesn't have same access

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post type and I added a custom taxonomy for this post type.
in the menu section under appearance tab, for my first (main) admin account there is some options to select created custom post type and it's taxonomies but after that I created another admin account but in this account only default posts and the categories is available and there is no custom post option there!
can any one help?
thank's a lot.

Answer (score 2):

there was not any problem with my new account.

I just realized that there is an option in wordpress that you can check what you want to show or hide in admin panel for each part.
and you can access these options from page setting button in top left corner of the page.

for example in menu section you can click on this button and choose menu types that you want to display in the list.

hope this answer help someone like me.